# Getting lambda in a Box-Cox equation

Tags: c#, python, perl, r, matlab

I have a set of values and I need to get the lambda for a Box-Cox equation. It's a normal curve (gaussian distribution). Does anyone know how to get optimal value for lambda in R, C#, MATLAB, or python or perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R: [package geoR, boxcox.fit](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geor/docs/boxcox.fit)

Answer (score 2):

`boxcox` in the `MASS` package

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has a lot of good curve fitting modules.  There is a cookbook recipe for [Linear Regression](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/LinearRegression).  If you need something more complex, there is an [optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the following packages are not listed in any of answers: 
You can use boxcax from scipy.stats in Python or in R you can use Boxcox in Caret package. You can read more about [resolving skewness for predictive modeling in this post.](http://shahramabyari.com/2015/12/21/data-preparation-for-predictive-modeling-resolving-skewness/)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is Gaussian (as you state in your question), then the optimal value of lambda is 1, i.e. it doesn't need to be transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) has a gaussian fit routine. PDL is a lot like Matlab except with the power of programming in Perl.